# Ошибка приведения типов T[] в IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#

Есть класс сортировки, в котором нужно реализовать Benchmark то есть время отработки сортировки, но получаю ошибку приведения типов

```
class SelectionSort : ISort
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Sort<T>(IEnumerable<T> inpurArray)
    {
        return Sort(inpurArray, Comparer<T>.Default);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Sort<T>(IEnumerable<T> inpurArray, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        //Cast to array
        var array = inpurArray.ToArray();
        //pos_min is short for position of min
        int Min;

        //find the min element in the unsorted 
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Min = i;//set pos_min to the current index of array
            //test against elements after j to find the smallest
            for (int j = i + 1; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                if (comparer.Compare(array[j], array[Min]) > 0)
                {
                    //pos_min will keep track of the index that min is in, this is needed when a swap happens
                    Min = j;
                }
            }
            //if pos_min no longer equals i than a smaller value must have been found, so a swap must occur
            if (Min != i)
            {
                T temp = array[i];

                array[i] = array[Min];

                array[Min] = temp;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    public TimeSpan Benchmark<T>(IEnumerable<T> count)
    {
        var array = count.ToArray();

        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int x = 0; x < array.Length; x++)
        {
            array = new T [rand.Next(1, 500)];
        }

        var time = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        array = Sort(array, Comparer<T>.Default);

        time.Stop();

        return time.Elapsed;
    }
}
```

Вот в этом месте:

```
array = Sort(array, Comparer<T>.Default);
```

Подскажите, что я делаю не так и как решить проблему? Спасибо

Comment: Просто добавьте `.ToArray()`: `array = Sort(array, Comparer.Default).ToArray();`

Comment: Еще вызывает недоумение код, предшествующий проблемной строке. Вы в цикле пересоздаете массив. Так и задумано?

Comment: @DmitryD. Я учусь, поэтому ошибок могу и не видеть, покажите как сделали бы вы, и где именно я допустил ошибку ? Большое спасибо

Comment: @DmitryD.Вы за эту часть говорите   **array = new T [rand.Next(1, 500)];** А как правильно ? потому что если написать просто array = rand.Next(1, 500); Получаю ошибку

Comment: Внутри метода `Benchmark` - никак. Код заполнения массива вынесите наружу. И заполняйте, например, вот так: `array[x] = rand.Next(1, 500);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно проинтерпретировали ошибку.
Компилятор говорит вам, что не может привести `IEnumerable<T>` в `T[]`, а не наоборот. Действительно, метод `Sort` возвращает `IEnumerable<T>`, а вы пытаетесь присвоить возвращаемое значение переменной типа `T[]`.
Попробуйте привести тип возвращаемого значения к типу `T[]` вызовом `.ToArray()`:

```
array = Sort(array, Comparer.Default).ToArray();
```